# saving custom taxonomy as post title

Tags: custom-taxonomy, title

I have two custom taxonomies; "name" and band". The first represents the name of the song, the second represents the band that made the song.

I want to automatically save a combination of those two custom taxonomies in the post title upon saving.

So in the following example: 
name = "Little Lion Man" 
band = "Mumford and sons" 
.. I want the post title to become "Mumford and sons - Little Lion Man"

The code I now have (and works!) is based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016516/replacing-the-title-of-a-post-with-a-custom-taxonomy-on-wordpress/13311841#13311841). However, what this code does is only get one custom taxonomy (in this case the song name, or 'name'). I want to put two custom taxonomy terms in the post title.

This is the code I have now, and I don't know where to begin. I'm not an expert on php.

```
add_action('save_post', 'update_term_title');
function update_term_title($post_id)
{
    if(defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) 
    return;
if(!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id))
    return;

$term1 = wp_get_post_terms($post_id, 'name', array('fields' => 'names'));
$term2 = wp_get_post_terms($post_id, 'band', array('fields' => 'names'));

$terms = $term1;

if(empty($terms)) 
    return;

$title = false; 
foreach($terms as $term) 
{
    if($term->parent) 
    {
        $parent = get_term($term->parent, 'name'); 
        $title = $term->name.' '.$parent->name;
        break;
    }
}
/*Default to first selected term name if no children were found*/
$title = $title ? $title : $terms[0]->name;

/*We must disable this hook and reenable from within
if we don't want to get caught in a loop*/
remove_action('save_post', 'update_term_title');
$update = array(
    'ID'=>$post_id,
    'post_name'=>sanitize_title_with_dashes($title),
    'post_title'=>$title
);
wp_update_post($update);
add_action('save_post', 'update_term_title');
}
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to make this work? It should be a minor modification of the code. Maybe make two loops?

Comment: Welcome to WPSE Lars! Can you explain exactly 'what isn't working'? What steps have you already taken to debug the code?

Comment: Hi @StephenHarris, I've updated the question to be able to get a better answer. Thanks for all the edits sofar, great community!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated Answer:

You're trying to mix a lot of things that you don't understand, by using the `$args` in `wp_get_post_terms` you don't need to run the `foreach` to hunt for child terms (is your custom taxonomy even hierarchical anyway?). As a catch-all you can just [`implode`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) the whole list and get the same result (but without seeing/knowing your schema I can't be sure it's actually what you want.)

```
<?php
add_action('save_post', 'update_term_title');
function update_term_title($post_id) {
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) return;
    if (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) return;

    $names = wp_get_post_terms($post_id, 'name', array('fields' => 'names'));
    // $names == array( 0 => 'name1'[, 1 => 'name2'[, 2 => ...]])
    $bands = wp_get_post_terms($post_id, 'band', array('fields' => 'names'));
    // $bands == array( 0 => 'band1'[, 1 => 'band2'[, 2 => ...]])

    // collapse parent and child terms
    $name = implode(' ', $names);
    // $name == "name1[ name2[ ...]]"
    $band = implode(' ', $bands);
    // $band == "band1[ band2[ ...]]"

    if ($name OR $band) {
        // concat name and band, use trim to clean the string if one is missing
        $title = trim(implode(' ', array($name, $band)));
        // $title == "name1[ name2[ ...]] band1[ band2[ ...]]"
        // disable and reenable hook from within to avoid a loop
        remove_action('save_post', 'update_term_title');
        $update = array(
            'ID' => $post_id,
            'post_name' => sanitize_title_with_dashes($title),
            'post_title' => $title,
        );
        wp_update_post($update);
        add_action('save_post', 'update_term_title');
    }
}
```

Normally I wouldn't suggest this method because of the disable/reenable hack, there is a filter for post data called `wp_insert_post_data` meant for altering the post data prior to the DB UPDATE/INSERT, but you'd probably have to understand quite a bit more to get past figuring out how to reference the taxonomy items that haven't yet been saved. The above method is technically quite expensive as it requires saving a post, requesting the post and then saving the post again

Old Answer:

> `wp_get_post_terms()` returns an array, not a string.
>   [wp_get_post_terms docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms)
>
> You need to treat `$term1` and `$term2` as arrays.
>
> ```
> $term1 = wp_get_post_terms($post_id, 'name', array('fields' => 'names'));
> $term2 = wp_get_post_terms($post_id, 'band', array('fields' => 'names'));
> # this assumes the first term in the taxonomy is the one you want
> $terms = array_pop($term1) . array_pop($term2);
> ```

Comment: or for fun:
`$terms = implode(' - ', wp_get_object_terms($post_id, array('band', 'name'), array('fields' => 'names'));`

Comment: Thanks, but I've updated the question so it's easier to answer.

Comment: Thanks @totels, it now says unexpected ; on the line             $title = trim(implode(' ', array($name, $band));
Quick answer; there is no hierarchy in both taxonomies.

Comment: Ooops, missing a closing parens `)`, fixed.

Comment: Works like a charm! I've made one edit to get a dash in between the band name and song title. Thanks a lot @totels!
`$title = trim(implode(' ', array($band, '-', $name)));`

Comment: Probably more accurately what you want for the dash is: `$title = trim(implode(' - ', array($band, $name)));`. (yours will work just find though) But both solutions technically will "break" if `$band` or `$name` is `null` or empty string `''`.

Comment: I have some songs with two bands attached to it, when it is a cover song. In that case I only want to use the first value for 'band'. What if I only wanted the first value of the array 'name' or 'band'? @totels

Comment: I've tried some code and this seemed to work for my previous question. I bet the syntax could be better, but it works.
        `$title = $bands[0] . ' - ' . $names[0];`

Comment: @LarsvanPeij that should (sorta) work just fine. You have no way of guaranteeing that the first item is going to be the one you want every time, but yes, that is an acceptable way of getting the first of each taxonomy for the title.